# Create a Git commit whose parents have an ancestry relation

Tags: git

`git-merge(1)` says:

```
           With --no-ff, create a merge commit in all cases, even when the merge could instead be
           resolved as a fast-forward.
```

However "in all cases" is not strictly accurate:

```
$ git merge --no-ff HEAD^^
Already up to date.
```

I think a rewording of "when the merge could instead of resolved as a fast-forward" is: when *`HEAD` is an ancestor of the input revision*. At that point a merge commit is not necessary but Git recognizes that you might want one anyway.

But when the reverse is true, i.e. the *input revision is an ancestor of `HEAD`*, the merge seems more unambiguously pointless. Apparently `git merge --no-ff` won't create a commit where one parent is an ancestor of the other. Despite being pointless, I don't think such a commit would actually pose a problem for git. I just can't figure out a way to create one through the CLI.

The reason I'm wondering about this is that I've got a script that operates on Git repos, and I've written some silly overwrought test logic that generates arbitrary repository histories and uses them as test inputs. My test logic is misbehaving because I wrote it on the assumption that `git merge --no-ff` always creates a commit. So, the *practical* solution is to just fix that false assumption in my test logic. But, it seems more fun and interesting to find out how to create these weird merge commits.

So, is there some lower-level CLI that can let me do this strange thing?

Answer (score 1):

Ah!

> Apparently git `merge --no-ff` won't create a commit where one parent is an ancestor of the other

This is not true! All I have to do is swap around `HEAD` and the input revision. The intention of `git merge --no-ff HEAD^^` is satisfied by:

```bash
OLD_HEAD=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
git checkout HEAD^^
git merge --no-ff $OLD_HEAD
```